# CSS not working with internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, incompatibility

I am making a website for a client, but for some reason internet explorer does not accept the markup. it is supposed to look like this: [image: Chrome/firefox]

which it does on chrome/firefox, but on all versions of Internet Explorer it shows up like this:
[image: Internet Explorer]

You can take a look at the CSS here: http://infinity4life.nl/
I Hope some of you may be able to help me with this, I thank you in advance.

Comment: how can we know the issue if we don't see the code?

Comment: You can click on the link and use your browsers' debug feature

Comment: FYI the output looks fine on IE10, but not on IE9.

Answer (score 1):

For the sidebar `ul.li`, add following attributes:

```
ul.menu li {
    float: left; /*new*/
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; /*new*/
}
```

For header text, remove all space at first. It's not right practice to control positioning by space. Then use `text-align: center` to make it in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I found what fixed the main problem. In the html at the end of a div i used

```
     </div><!-- end of div-->
```

Internet explorer did not understand this, so I had to add a space:

```
     </div> <!-- end of div-->
```

this basicly ruined all the CSS because it would inherit styles it shouldn't. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Removing `font-size:1em` from your `#header FORM .inputbox` seems to fix the ginormous input field issue in IE.

Comment: Thanks, that solved that problem. It has however revealed that the page title isn't visible. Any ideas on that?